# Write text and tables in to word, with whitespaces/enters

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, text-mining, opennlp

I'm writing `text` and `text` from `tables` into a word document.

With the following code the `tables` are placed under the right `paragraphs`.

```
 Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = xdoc.getBodyElementsIterator();
               while (iter.hasNext())
               {
                  IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
                  if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph)
                  { 
                      relevantText.setText(((XWPFParagraph) elem).getText());

                  } else if (elem instanceof XWPFTable)
                  {     
                      tabellen.setText(((XWPFTable) elem).getText());

                  }
               }
```

Now when I try to make a `whitespace/enter` with `addBreak()` or `addCarriageReturn()` the order of my document is wrong. The `table text` is placed after all the `text`.

Has anyone a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago. did you create 2 diffrent runs for the paragraphs and the tables?

Because I did, and when I changed it to 1 run it did work for me.

Like this:

```
XWPFRun text = paragraph.createRun();
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. I did use `two runs`, one for text and one for tables. When I use one `run` its goes well.